# Installed gitlab, but only nginx welcome page shows

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I installed gitlab using its [installation guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/install/installation.md). Everything was OK, but when I open localhost:80 in the browser all I see it the message **Welcome to nginx!**. I can't find any log file with any errors in it.

I am running Ubuntu in VirtualBox. My /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab config file reads:

```
# GITLAB
# Maintainer: @randx
# App Version: 3.0

upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/gitlab/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  listen 192.168.1.1:80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80;
  server_name aridev-VirtualBox;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  root /home/gitlab/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks fairly similar to mine (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/nginx/nginx.conf.tpl#L80-L118). Do you properly start GitLab services? (https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitlab/gitlabd)

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: No sorry. A sysadmin started from scratch and nailed it over a few days. He found it painful to install, but that was quite an old version compared to today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) says:

```
Server names are defined using the server_name directive and determine which server block is used for a given request.
```

That means in your case that that you have to enter *aridev-VirtualBox* within your browser instead of localhost.

To get this working you have to enter *aridev-VirtualBox* within your local [Hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and point it to the IP of your VirtualBox PC.

This would look something like follows:

```
192.168.1.1 aridev-VirtualBox
```

Answer (score 5):

I removed `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` to get rid of that problem.

Comment: No dice, sorry. Resulted in "Bad gateway" after nginx restart.

Comment: this will work for people on ubuntu 13.04 who installed nginx from apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

Try following both orkoden's advice of removing the default site from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ but also comment out your `listen` line since the default implied line there should be sufficient.

Also, make sure that when you make changes to these configurations, shut down both the gitlab and nginx services and start them in the order of gitlab first, followed by nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration file is right. `# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab`

Maybe I think your gitlab file link is wrong.

So Example:

> ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab
>
> pls check default content == your /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab 
>   content
>
> after

Answer (score 0):

Me I changed this line :

```
proxy_pass http://gitlab;
```

by this :

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
```

3000 is the port of my unicorn server.

moreover I did a `chown root:ngnix` on the conf file and it work now.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but it may happen when there is a previously installed nginx.
`$ gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
or restart will not complain but the previous nginx instance may actually running instead of the one under gitlab.
This just happened to me.

Shutdown and disable this old nginx instance and do again:
`$ gitlab-ctl reconfigure`